# A way to compare SQL bit to char in two different tables

Tags: sql, sql-server, case, where-clause

I have two tables, table A with column A which takes a bit value and Table B with column B that takes a Char(1) value the values are either 'C' or 'D' and I want them to match the bit of 0 or 1 respectively is there a way I can compare these two like so?

Thanks!

Comment: Sounds like maybe you want to use a `CASE`. With it, you can tell SQL to show a 'C' when the bit is 0, or 'D' when it is 1, or vice versa.

Comment: @jw11432 Thanks I went with the case and it worked

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could enumerate the combinations. Say you want a match, then use the following condition:

```
(ta.a = 0 and tb.b = 'C') or (ta.a = 1 and tb.b = 'D')
```

Alternatively, use a `case` expression:

```
ta.a = case tb.b when 'C' then 0 when 'D' then 1 end
```